# Redux async actions: Does it make any difference to put initial dispatch into the try block?

Tags: redux, async-await, try-catch, dispatch

Consider I am making a pretty generic api call using redux async action. There is an `"INIT"` dispatch and either `"SUCCESS"` or `"FAILURE"`, regarding of the result.

**Does it make any difference to put the `"INIT"` dispatch into the `try catch` block?**

**OPTION A** (outside the `try catch` block):

```
export const doSomething = data => async dispatch => {
  dispatch(doSomethingInit()) // <-- outside try block
  try {
    let response = await client.get("/api")
    if (response) {
      dispatch(doSomethingSuccess(response.data))
    }
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch(doSomethingFailure(error))
  }
}
```

**OPTION B** (inside the `try catch` block):

```
export const doSomething = data => async dispatch => {
  try {
    dispatch(doSomethingInit()) // <-- inside the try block
    let response = await client.get("/api")
    if (response) {
      dispatch(doSomethingSuccess(response.data))
    }
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch(doSomethingFailure(error))
  }
}
```

I would say it is just a subtle inessential detail, however I do spend a minute thinking about it almost every time I write a new async action… :/

Comment: I think `dispatch(doSomethingInit())` should never throw an error so better not put it in the try block. You put `await client.get("/api")` in the try block because you **expect** it can throw an error and handle that error in the catch. If you wrote the code without the `async` syntax sugar you'd write: `dispatch(doSomethingInit());client.get("/api").then(happyHandler, errorHandler)` so the first dispatch is not part of what the error handler should handle.

Comment: @HMR Yes, `dispatch(doSomethingInit())` should never throw – it is used for updating UI and logging. It does make sense as you put it. Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually avoid thinking that things will not `throw`.

What if it throws? What code is going to handle it? You might have an outer `try-catch` block, but now something that happened during `doSomething` is being handled somewhere else.

I think that since your function/thunk is "trying" to `doSomething`, it should be responsible for **trying** and **catching** anything that might happen during its life cycle. Even if, in theory, it wouldn't happen at that point.

So I usually go with **Option B**.

```
export const doSomething = data => async dispatch => {
  try {
    dispatch(doSomethingInit()) // <-- inside the try block
    let response = await client.get("/api")
    if (response) {
      dispatch(doSomethingSuccess(response.data))
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);                   // YOU MIGHT LOG IT HERE
    dispatch(doSomethingFailure(error))
  }
}
```

I also think the code reads better with everything inside the `try-catch` block.

Comment: Thank you for your insight. You are probably right that it is always a better choice to put all the function calls in the `try-catch` block (which means no more labour than literally switch those 2 LOC). Therefore, I would rather stick to Option B.